# How to Monetize Google Sheets Add-On BUT NOT with Stripe

Tags: google-sheets, stripe-payments, google-apps

We have built a Google Sheets add-on and we'd like to start monetizing it.

All the discussions I've found so far were about using Stripe. The problem is that we live in Czechia which is not supported to by Stripe and I don't want to start creating e.g. US entity just for the sake of receiving payments via Stripe.

Is anyone using any alternative to Stripe for monetization of Google Sheets add-on?

Comment: you can use proxy

Comment: I believe the money can only be paid out to a business entity in a supported country, no?